# NodeManager not started in Hadoop Yarn

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I have setup hadoop and yarn in standalone mode for now.
I am trying to start all process in yarn. All process are started except nodemanager. It is throwing jvm error everytime.

```
 [root@ip-10-100-223-16 hadoop-0.23.7]# sbin/yarn-daemon.sh start nodemanager
starting nodemanager, logging to /root/hadoop-0.23.7/logs/yarn-root-nodemanager-ip-10-100-223-16.out
Unrecognized option: -jvm
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

What can be the issue? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You might have a look at this ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-3879

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following link has a patch for the above issue : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-3879

in **bin/yarn** script, we need to comment following lines.  Here :
    **'-'  : shows removal of lines

     '+' : shows addition of lines**

```
elif [ "$COMMAND" = "nodemanager" ] ; then
   CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:$YARN_CONF_DIR/nm-config/log4j.properties
   CLASS='org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager'
-  if [[ $EUID -eq 0 ]]; then
-    YARN_OPTS="$YARN_OPTS -jvm server $YARN_NODEMANAGER_OPTS"
-  else
-    YARN_OPTS="$YARN_OPTS -server $YARN_NODEMANAGER_OPTS"
-  fi
+  YARN_OPTS="$YARN_OPTS -server $YARN_NODEMANAGER_OPTS"
 elif [ "$COMMAND" = "proxyserver" ] ; then
   CLASS='org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.WebAppProxyServer'
   YARN_OPTS="$YARN_OPTS $YARN_PROXYSERVER_OPTS"
```

Above patch is available on [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12515053/MAPREDUCE-3879.patch.txt) location.

Courtesy [LorandBendig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1050422/lorand-bendig) for helping me .